# Determine the common ratio $r$ of the geometric sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Determine the common ratio $r$ of the geometric sequence

$$5,{ 5 }^{ c+1 },{ 5 }^{ 2c+1 },{ 5 }^{ 3c+1 },...$$

Would it just be $\\ \frac { { 5 }^{ c+1 } }{ 5 } $?

Comment: try dividing all those numbers by 5

Comment: Your expression is correct. It would look prettier as $5^c$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how would it simplify to $5^c$?

Comment: Rewrite the numerator using the rule that $a^{m+n}=(a^m)(a^n)$

Comment: We have $5^{c+1}=5^c\cdot 5^1$. Now "cancel."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $5^c$

The common ratio can be solved using the following formula:

$$a_n= a_1 * r^{n-1}$$

Let $n=4$,
$a_4 = 5^{3c+1}$ (fourth term),
and $a_1=5$

So we get

$$5^{3c+1}=5*r^{4-1}$$
$$\frac{5^{3c}*5}{5}=r^{3}$$
$$5^{3c}=r^{3}$$
$$r=\sqrt[3]{5^{3c}}$$
$$r=(5^{3c})^{\frac{1}{3}} \Rightarrow 5^c$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!